# How do I make puppeteer click on link?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to make a scraper with puppeteer, that opens a site, uses its search bar and opens the first link.

That is the code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    
 (async () => {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
        
     await page.click('[name=query]');
    await page.keyboard.type("(Weapon)");
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.waitForSelector('div[class="search-results"]', {timeout: 100000});
});
```

The problem is I can't make it open the first link from the search results, I tried to use page.click() But all of the search results are the same except the URL.

What I want to know is how can I make it open the first link from search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're more ways to solve this. I recommend experimenting with it a bit, so you learn different ways of doing this.

```js
await page.click('.search-results a');
```

it turns out Puppeteer always click on the first element it finds, so if you want the first one, this will be enough.

Or you can select all the links and then click on the first one:

```js
const resultLinks = await page.$$('.search-results a');
resultLinks[0].click();
```

It'd be better to include a condition here as well, so you don't end up with an error because no element was found:

```js
const resultLinks = await page.$$('.search-results a');
if (resultLinks.length) resultLinks[0].click();
```

There're more ways, so if you want to learn more, please refer to the [API documenttion](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md).

Comment: It doesn't click the link and I think I know why is that below search-results there are the item elements and below each of them there is a title element in which is the Link, What do I do?

Comment: I tested it on my site, I'm quite sure it does click on the first link. However, the site shows some error (timeout) when searching now, so you actually never get the results. Plus you need to learn how to debug your code, so you can verify if it does or doesn't work. A good start is running your script in non-headless mode.

Comment: How do I run it in non-headless mode?

Comment: Method `puppeteer.launch()` could accept option object as the first argument, so you can pass in `{ headless: false }`. See the documentation I linked: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions

Comment: I ran it in headless and it did everything fine and clicked on the right link but It extracted the info from the search results? so strange...

Comment: I don't have all information you do, if you have multiple problems with what you're doing, I know only about this one with clicking on the first link. That's what I answered. I think you can manage the rest with the documentation and debugging.

Comment: Yes, I understand you helped me for what I asked which I am really grateful for and if I find myself unable to fix it i'll just post another question here.

Comment: @Crashalot: If you want to talk to me more, there's a link in my profile to my LinkedIn. I usually respond within a day if the message makes sense :D

Comment: thanks. just sent. the message makes sense; the q is if you're free and interested. :)